# bootstrap 3 navbar list items overlap with navbar brand

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a problem with BS3 navbar, when i change the size of the screen, navbar list items goes behind navbar brand image.

I would like navbar items to collapse into hamburger menu before they reach navbar brand. How can I achieve that?

Here is my HTML code:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
     <head>
     <meta charset = "UTF-8"> 
    <!-- BS, JS, FONTS -->
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
     <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
     <!-- CSS -->  
     <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "navbarProb.css"/>
     </head>
     <body id="index" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
    <!-- NAVBAR -->
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
       <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- MOBILE NAVBAR -->   
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
        </button> 
      <a class = "navbar-brand" href = "#listItem1"> 
       <img src = "https://image.ibb.co/jN2AaV/logo.jpg">
      </a>  
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
       <li><a href="#listItem1">listItem1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#listItem2">listItem23</a></li>  
    <!-- DROPDOWN NAVBAR -->   
       <li class="dropdown">
         <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">listItem3<span class="caret"></span></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#listItem4">listItem4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#listItem5">listItem5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#listItem6">listItem6</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">listItem</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">listItem</a></li>
         </ul>
       </li>    
       <li class="dropdown">
         <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">listItem<span class="caret"></span></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#listItem7">listItem7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">listItem</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">listItem</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">listItem</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">listItem</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">listItem</a></li>    
         </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#listItem8">listItem8</a></li>   
       <li><a href="#listItem9">listItem9</a></li>
       <li><a href="#listItem10">listItem10</a></li>   
        </ul>
      </div>
       </div>
     </nav>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@j.b

Bootstrap converts the navigation to hamburger below 767px and in your expected scenario, it should convert after 1021px which is not possible if you want to make it possible you have to write a media query `@media (max-width: 1021px)` and your hamburger code.

let me know if you need anything.

Comment: Hello Atul, thanks for getting involved! when i change media query in my css to @media (min-width:1021px) {
  .navbar-right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
  }
} , navbar items drop down to second row when they reach navbar brand...

Comment: you don't have to put CSS absolute you just need to put the hamburger code.